# What are the practical applications of infinite series to Perpetuity?

Tags: finance, bonds, discount-rate

I've already know that you can derive present value formula of a perpetuity through infinite series. But, one can argue that it's not really practical since you can just use the derived formula. So, I wanna know if there's a much more practical usage of infinite series to perpetuities (and a preferably easy concept).

Comment: How do you interpret the formula without going to the infinite series?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.